# OnClick method not being called inside table

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, onclick

The `_onButtonClick` method is not being called inside the `renderTeamsTable` method.
I have tried binding inside `renderTeamsTable`, still no luck.

I can get `_onButtonClick` to work on a button in the render.

```js
    export class FetchTeamData extends Component {
        displayName = FetchTeamData.name

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { teams: [], loading: true, showComponent: false};
        this._onButtonClick = this._onButtonClick.bind(this);

      fetch('api/team')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ teams: data, loading: false });



      });
    }

    _onButtonClick() {
      this.setState({
        showComponent: true,
        loading : true
      });
      console.log('method is called')
    }

    static renderTeamsTable(teams) {
      return (<table className='table'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Team</th>
          <th>Division</th>
          <th>Conference</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          {teams.map(team =>
            <tr key={team.id} onClick={this._onButtonClick} >
                  <td>{team.team}</td>
                  <td>{team.division}</td>
                  <td>{team.conference}</td>

      </tr>
      )}
      </tbody>
    </table>)
    }



    render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading
      ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
        : FetchTeamData.renderTeamsTable(this.state.teams);

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>NBA Teams</h1>
        <p>All current teams in NBA</p>

        <Button onClick={this._onButtonClick}>Button</Button>
        {this.state.showComponent ?
        <FetchPlayerFromTeamData team = {'Miami Heat'}/> :
        null
        }

        {contents}

    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed static from `renderTeamsTable` and then called the method as `this.renderTeamsTable(this.state.teams);`

This enabled the `onClick` being called as expected

Updated code

```
export class FetchTeamData extends Component {
  displayName = FetchTeamData.name

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { teams: [], loading: true, showComponent: false, selectedTeam: [] };

    fetch('api/team')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ teams: data, loading: false });
      });
  }

  selectTeamOnClick(team) {
    this.setState({
      showComponent: true,
      loading: false,
      selectedTeam: team
    });
  }

  renderTeamsTable(teams) {
    return (<table className='table'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Team</th>
          <th>Division</th>
          <th>Conference</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {teams.map(team =>
          <tr key={team.id} onClick={() => this.selectTeamOnClick(team.team)} >
            <td>{team.team}</td>
            <td>{team.division}</td>
            <td>{team.conference}</td>
          </tr>
        )}
      </tbody>
    </table>)
  }

  render() {

    let contents = this.state.loading
      ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
      : this.renderTeamsTable(this.state.teams);


    return (
      <div>
        <h1>NBA Teams</h1>
        <p>All current teams in NBA</p>

        {this.state.showComponent ?
          <button onClick={() => this.setState({ showComponent: false })}>
            Clear Players</button> :
          null
        }

        {this.state.showComponent ?
          <FetchPlayerFromTeamData team={this.state.selectedTeam} /> :
          null
        }
        {contents}



      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `this` is not what you think it is in a `static` function. If you don't need `renderTeamsTable` to be static, then just remove that keywords and replace `FetchTeamData.renderTeamsTable` with `ftd.renderTeamsTable` and create `ftd` as an instance of that class, and it should start working. Otherwise, pass `this` as argument to the static method.

Comment: It would be better to either
A) Use a lambda function
B) bind the _onButtonClick method in the constructor.